Which thread handles a realtime callback in Jack (audio)?
Context
I am working on a application that has a Qt GUI and does audio processing with Jack in C++.
In order to decouple the GUI from audio processing, I want them to run in different threads.
Potentially, there may be other additional threads involved.
Question
How does the system determine, in which thread the audio callback registered via jack_set_process_callback is being run?
Knowing this decisive, ie. if there are more threads involved.
Simplified Pseudocode
JackClient::run starts a seperate thread that is sets itself to sleep but is used to handle the audio callback registered via jack_set_process_callback.
It seems to work - the audio callback is handled by the sleeping dedicated audio thead - but why?
main.cpp:
#include ".../model/model.h"
#include ".../view/mainwindow.h"
#include "controller.h"
#include ".../audio/jack.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // 1. Init Jack Client
  // and start dedicated
  // dummy thread to process
  // audio:
  JackClient jack(...);
  {
    jack.init();
    jack.run(); // <- start audio thread
  }

  // 2. Start GUI
  // and run GUI mainloop
  // in main thread:
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  auto model = Model(...);
  auto view = MainWindow();
  Controller controller(
      &model,
      &view,
      &jack,
      viewResolution
  );
  controller.run(); <- GUI main loop

  auto ret = a.exec();

  // stop audio thread:
  jack.exit();

  return ret;
}

jack.cpp:
// the audio callback:
int processAudio(
    jack_nframes_t nframes,
    void* arg
);

MaybeError JackClient::init() {
    {
      jack_status_t status;
      jack_options_t options = JackNullOption;
      client = jack_client_open(
          clientName,
          options,
          &status
      );
      if( !client ) {
        throw QString("error opening client");
      }
    }
    // set process callback:
    jack_set_process_callback(
        client,
        &processAudio,
        this
    );
    // create ports:
    ...
  
  return {};
}

MaybeError JackClient::run() {
  if( jack_activate(client) ) {
    return "cannot activate client";
  }
  workerStop = false;
  worker = std::thread([this]{
      while(!workerStop) {
        sleep(1);
      };
  });
  return {};
}

void JackClient::exit() {
  if(!client) {
    return;
  }
  workerStop = true;
  worker.join();
  jack_client_close(
      client
  );
}

I read the Jack documentation and looked into the official example clients, but couldn't find any good explanation or even a hint where to search.

I think, jack implicitly creates a new thread in which the callback functions will be executed. I modified simple_client.c to print thread ids in main() and process(), and got two different thread ids.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
